# Running dropwizard 1.1.2 on heroku

Tags: heroku, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard 1.1.2 application that works ok locally. I try to deploy this to heroku and I read that I need to override the ports values to be provided by heroku in the Procfile, something like the following:

web:  java $JAVA_OPTS -Ddw.http.port=$PORT -Ddw.http.adminPort=$PORT -jar target/My_Website-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server target/classes/app.yml

This however is for older versions of Dropwizard and I am unable to find documentation for Dropwizard 1.1.2 working with heroku. If I don't provide the port information, heroku app starts, then crashes with the following message:

Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

What would be the correct Procfile and config.yml contents for using Dropwizard 1.1.2 with heroku? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. You need to pass only -Ddw.server.applicationConnectors[0].port=$PORT and not -Ddw.server.adminConnectors[0].port=$PORT in the Procfile